# Second WAN/LAN in office, want to share printers between them

Tags: networking, router, lan, network-printer, dsl

My business is growing so I've decided to purchase a second DSL line, to separate two departments to allow for more bandwidth usage.

Previously I had a network printer that served both departments. With the addition of the second DSL line, I'm potentially going to have two separate LANs.

How can I set it up so that the new LAN still has access to the Network Printer, but ensure that they are still using the new DSL line?

Comment: You can probably achieve this with what you have, please can you provide the make and model of the existing router?

Comment: It's a bit of a No-Name, Black Box, all I know is it runs http://www.pfsense.org/

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of VLANs with separate default gateways but sharing internal routes could accomplish this.  You can use a couple of routers with [DD-Wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) installed to create the VLANs.